# How to restore XAMPP server from backup?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I used XAMPP on my linux computer for hosting simple database application. I had it installed in `/opt/lampp/` directory. I copied whole `/opt/lampp/` directory from backup to new machine. When I run `/opt/lampp/xampp start`, I get

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-4...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
```

I can connect to web-server, but it cannot connect to database. When I try to manage database from phpMyAdmin as root user, I get `#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server`.

When I try to stop server, I get

```
Stopping XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-4...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
```

I have directory with name of database in `/opt/lampp/var/mysql` containing .frm and .ibd files, but I don't have sql dumps.

- How can I chceck status of mysql server? (It should be installed locally somewhere in `/opt/lampp` directory.)
- Do I need to modify something on my new system outside of `/opt/lampp` directory? (Create user, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Only thing needed is to create `mysql` user. I copied line from `/etc/passwd` from backup.

Comment: You should mark your answer as solved so others know to look for it here.